# mootools and jQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I've got a simple form in a page that is loading Mootools and JQuery. JQuery is in no conflict mode, which seems like it ought to cause no problems.

There's a form element called "name"--

```
<input class="required" id="sendname" name="sendname" value="">
```

And I'm trying to attach a click event to it using **Mootools** to update something else when the name box is clicked:

```
$('sendname').addEvent('click', function(e){
    // do stuff.
});
```

The problem is that the click event never gets added.

---

This error appears on load:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEvent' of null
```

When I try to interact with the element in a js console, I get the following error:

```
> $('sendname').setProperty('value', 'test');
TypeError: Object sendname has no method 'setProperty'</strike>
```

---

EDIT: the previous was fixed by loading a newer Mootools. However, the click event still isn't functioning properly, though it throws no errors or warning.

This code works fine in almost any situation I've used it in. I assume there's some issue with jQuery conflicting, but the fact that the `$` notation works seems to confirm that noConflict mode is operational. Any ideas?

Comment: Another random thought:  Is it critical you use both JavaScript libraries here?  I'd choose Mootools **OR** jQuery and convert the other scripts to use same.

Comment: @Sparky672-- you're right, I'd much prefer to stick with mootools. This is not my choice however, and the client is using both in the site.

Comment: @julio:  Next step would be to post more of your relevant code, post a JSFiddle, or post a link to your page.

Comment: @julio:  Also, remove all jQuery code (temporarily) just to verify that your Mootools code works as intended.

Comment: @Sparky672-- here's a fiddle for you-- http://jsfiddle.net/uSwzL/1/. Looks like what was happening in my page was that the jQuery was getting loaded after the mootools code-- so the noConflict() statement was not being honored.

Comment: You can load the jquery after the mootools code, as long as the `noConflict()` part comes before loading jquery. Or you can always replace all `$` with `jquery`. About my reply, note that `$('myElement')` is an example and it will have to be updated to whatever element type, the most common uses are an **hash** (#) for an id and a **period** (.) for a class.

Comment: which version of mootools is this? setPropery is 1.11 which has no `noConflict` mode - in which mootools reverts to `document.id` only if `$` is already defined. looks like `$ == jQuery` for you. if you are on 1.2.3+ mootools, you can reference `document.id("someid")` instead. else, you need to put jQuery in `noConflict` mode so it does not overwrite MooTools one. I'd upgrade to 1.2.5 or 1.3.2 though and just use `document.id` or bind it to $ in a closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the comments to the OP, the issue was the load-order of the jQuery/Mootools scripts. The jQuery noConflict was being loaded too late, and causing problems. Please see jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/uSwzL/1/

Answer (score 5):

You are targetting the element wrongly... I think this has nothing to do with a possible conflict.

In this case you need to add the **hash** for an id or a **period** for a class, like this:

```
$('#sendname').addEvent('click', function(e){
    // do stuff.
});
```

Notice the **#** in `#sendname`

Comment: @jackJoe-- I'm not disputing your answer, but when I tried something using that # notation I got: $('#sendname').addEvent('click', function(e){ alert('yo')});
TypeError: $("#sendname") is null

However, using the original format throws no error (though it still doesn't seem to add the click event)-- $('sendname').addEvent('click', function(e){ alert('yo')});
<input id="sendname" class="required" value="" name="sendname">

Comment: @julio:  There is absolutely no doubt about it.  When selecting by ID, you **must** put the hash in front of the name:  `$('#myID_name')`

Comment: @Sparky672-- are you using jQuery notation, or am I totally misunderstanding the mootools syntax? From: http://mootools.net/docs/core125/core/Element/Element

Examples:
Get a DOM Element by ID:
var myElement = $('myElement');

Comment: @julio:  That is proper **jQuery** syntax.  Perhaps you should clarify your question.

Comment: @Sparky-- clarified in question. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: __downvoted:__ if you use `jQuery("#someid").addEvent()` it will not work. jQuery returns its own methods on the prototype and the actual element is as `$("#someid")[0]` - so you have to do `$("#someid")[0].addEvent()` for it to work - mootools is prototypical and needs access to the element. HOWEVER. this won't work in IE < 9 as IE does not allow you to prototype Element. MooTools gets around that by adding the element methods on the object directly when you pass it through a $ selector - and an element, returned by jQuery or vanilla js won't get `.addEvent` in IE8 or lower. Just saying.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff The OP needs the hash in this case. I never heard of jquery calling elements (other than tags) without specifying their selector type. I may have forgotter the [0] but the main thing in my reply is calling the element correctly. This is not guesswork and I would arrive to the airport by myself on time :)

Comment: the point is, in mootools - if you call the element directly - and addEvent is a mootools element method - it needs the `Element.prototype.addEvent` to be set or `elobj.addEvent` to be set. it won't be in ie6,7 and 8. you cannot combine jquery and mootools this way and hope to produce cross-browser code.

Answer (score 1):

MooTools has Dollar Safe mode that *automatically* releases the $ to other libs as long as MooTools is loaded last.

If Dollar Safe mode is active, you need to use:

```
document.id('SomeElementID').someMethod()
```

What is happening in the example you are giving, is that you're using jQuery to select the element, and a MooTools method on the result. The thing is, jQuery returns the jQuery object which has no such 'addEvent' method on it. MooTools works on the actual elements so you need to select them with a MooTools query method first: $ == document.id or $$ == document.search

You can cache document.id to a var for convenience if you want:

```
var $M = document.id;
$M('sendname').addEvent(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any problem even loading jquery.js after other $ based library loaded:

```
<script>$=function(){alert('hell');}</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
$();
alert(jQuery.trim('  hello '));
</script>
```

Even in php framework html template:

```
<script>
function on_doc_ready()
         {jQuery(function($)
                 {$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
                  $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
                 }
                );
         }
function load_jquery_ui()
         {var s2=document.createElement('scr'+'ipt');
          s2.setAttribute('onload', 'on_doc_ready();');
          s2.src='/app/idm/statics/jQuery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js';
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s2);
         }
function load_jquery_after_mootools()
         {var s1=document.createElement('scr'+'ipt');
          s1.src='/app/idm/statics/jQuery/js/jquery-1.9.0.js';
          s1.setAttribute('onload', '$.noConflict();load_jquery_ui();');
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s1);
         }
load_jquery_after_mootools();
<script>
```